# Syntax error when binding a model object to a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to bind a model object to a javascript array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tests = [];
    tests = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.TestList));
</script>
```

I get a small red syntax-error marker under the semicolon. If I remove the semicolon, I get the same red marker in the next line. This is inside a partial view inside the last div just before the `</div>` tag.

What am I missing in this piece of code?

Comment: This is just an issue with intellisense; it won't actually generate a runtime error in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it this

```
 tests = @(Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.TestList)))
```

semicolon not required in the end.